# Can we inject our code to another sub process?

Tags: c#, c++

Is it possible to inject the code into another sub process? Let's say we have Silverlight plugin in the browser.. We want to inject our code (something like Snoop) into that plugin's process. When I'm using Spy++, I can receive the event from the plugin.. SO, I'm assuming that it is possible to inject the code as well..

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I'm currently looking at the code of Snoop and this article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/winspy.aspx.. I understand that we can inject our code into other process.. My question is how to hook to other "sub" process..

Please take a look at this screenshot.. I'm trying to hook into "Microsoft SIlverlight" (Red arrow) but it doesn't work.. It would be great if you guys can share me some code example for hooking sub-process.. Thanks..

[image: SL process on Spy++]

Comment: What do you mean by `inject code`? Like modify the program flow?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are WinAPI calls to intercept messages to a window which Spy++ uses, not code injection.

Comment: Hi Blender, I'm talking about something like that http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/winspy.aspx

Comment: Yes.. like modify the existing UI or flow.. something like a tool called snoop

Comment: "sub-process"? You mean **window**?

Comment: Hi wj32, Please kindly take a look at the screenshot.. The process that is pointed by "Green" arrow is a "main" process. The sub-process is the one that is pointed with red arrow..

Comment: @Michael Sync: Yes, that's a window. If you want to set a hook, use SetWindowsHookEx, as indicated in the answers. Otherwise, your question is not very specific. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yap.. I'm using SetWindowsEx to hook the window "MS Silverlight" but it doesn't work. but I'm able to hook the main-level window (e.g. Window 000305A8 )

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite "injection", but [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990.aspx) is pretty useful.

If you *really need* injection, take a look at what [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) does.

Comment: Yes.. Currently, this code _messageHookHandle = ::SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, procAddress, hinstDLL, threadID); is being used in Snoop.. I'm just wondering if we can hook into "sub" process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to hook to other process.

For more information read the chapter 22 from the book “Programming Applications for Microsoft 
Windows” by Jeffrey Richter. It contains different ways of hooking. I think this may help you.

API’s like SetWindowsHookEx(),CreateRemoteThread() ect will help you to hook to other process.

Comment: I understand that we can hook to other process.. Can we hook to other sub-process? For example: IE Process -> Windows Frame Tab -> TabWindowsClass -> Shell DocObject View -> IE Server -> MS Silverlight..

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't have 'sub-processes,' but processes can have child processes. If child processes couldn't be hooked, you wouldn't be able to hook most running applications as they're child processes of explorer. Spy++ is showing you child windows, not processes. If you want to hook only input on a particular window you'll need to filter based on the active control.

**Note:** You're in Spy++ *windows* view, you can switch to processes view with the gears button.